# Toggle comment color in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Since I write a lot of comments in my code I would like to toggle color of them. They can be default color(grayish) while I'm looking at the code, but when reading and writing them I would like to have a toggle button that will change color of them. I have added this code to color scheme:

```
"rules":
[   
    {
  "name": "text",
  "scope": "text",
    "foreground": "#E7E7E7",
    "caret": "#E7E7E7",
  },
//   {
//    "name": "Comment",
//     "scope": "comment",
//     "foreground": "#E7E7E7"
// },
```

Is there any way to add a key binding that will toggle commenting bottom code.

Any solution that allows me to toggle color of the comment is fine, key binding plug-in, etc.